# How to add city specific products in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to add products which can be shipped to specific cities.

Also I want to show list of cities on product detail page.

Apart from this I want user to enter city / pin(zip)code before he presses add to cart button.

I am also looking for the same option in search facets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catalog -> manage product -> custom option as dropdown add your cities then create module(if you would like to modify coming data from drop down) for cities and call custom option in view page.